# Git commit-msg hook: prefix commit based on part of branch name

Tags: regex, git, shell, githooks

My branch name pattern is as following 
ticketId_ticketDescription
e.g
**MIT-1018**-make-goto-redirection-smarter

so i want each commit to be prefixed by ticketId in this case it is 
[**MIT-1018**]

So if i commit

git commit -am"**This is a commit message**"
so message should be "**MIT-1018: This is a commit message**"

This is my try

```
#!/bin/bash
ticket=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD | sed -e 's/MIT-[0-9]+//'`
echo $ticket
comment=`cat $1`
search=`grep "$ticket" $1`
if [ -n "$ticket" ] && [ -z "$search" ]
then
echo "$ticket: $comment" > $1
fi
```

but this add the whole branch name as a prefix not the TicketId only

Comment: Your example is not clear, Can you clearly state the sample input and expected output needed for you? and what is your argument to the script "`$1`"?

Comment: Is the `TicketId` string have fixed length characters? `3` characters followed by `4` digits?

Comment: @Inian
i just highlighted it in the description
git commit -am"This is a commit message" so message should be "MIT-1018: This is a commit message"

Comment: @Inian
Yes it always start with <MIT> then followed by any number of digits 4 or more or less

Comment: Refer my answer below and don't forget to accept/upvote the solution once you find it solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`regex` in `bash`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern) with character classes, `[[:alnum:]]` and `[[:digit:]]` to extract the ticket identifier as you need.

```
$ ticket="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
$ commitMessage="This is a commit message"

# Assuming the variable has the string "MIT-1018-make-goto-redirection-smarter"
# ticket="MIT-1018-make-goto-redirection-smarter"

$ [[ $ticket =~ (([[:alnum:]]{3})-([[:digit:]]{3,})).* ]] && ticketID=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
$ printf "%s\n" "$ticketID: $commitMessage"
MIT-1018: This is a commit message
```